# Symfony 3.4 - Encrypt BEFORE login_check. Authentication

Tags: php, symfony

At present, I am on Symfony 3 and I work on the authentification. My passwords in the database are encrypted. For the authentication, symfony get back the data send by the form of connection and transmit them in my login_check root. I wish to encrypt the password of the user before symfony transmits it in login_check.
Here is a part of my security.yml. If you need more information, do not hesitate to ask to me for it. Thank a lot !

PS : Sorry for my english ^^

```
intranet:
        pattern:   ^/intranet
        anonymous: ~
        provider:     Auditeurs
        form_login:
            default_target_path: intranet_dashboard
            login_path: intranet_login
            check_path: intranet_login_check
        logout:
            path:       intranet_logout #nom de la route
            target:     /intranet/


providers:
    Auditeurs:
        entity:
            class:    AppBundle\Entity\Auditeur
            property: username
```

Answer (score -1):

As soon the `login_check` request hits your Symfony application, it is sent to the firewall, that *hashes* the password and compares it with the database. Hence "encrypting" it before does not quite make sense, you just have a few lines of routing "plumbing" that are executed. What you most probably want to do is to hash passwords client side, using some Javascript library. Such one is [SJCL](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/).

The benefits of such an approach are minimal though if your website is served over HTTPS (as it should).

Last note: password are *hashed* (using the *encoder* from Symfony configuration), not *encrypted*. A hash is a one-way function. On the other hand, encrypted passwords could be recovered from the database (which should never happen). BCrypt is advised (I suspect that's now the default in Symfony).

Comment: If you hash passwords client-side then the hash *is* the password and you still have all the same plaintext/replay problems. Use HTTPS.

Comment: Could you please detail the scenario of such an attack? I think the point there is not to leak the ciphertext password, but replays can be set up a lot of different ways, if the connection is intercepted (for instance cookies). Hence the advise to use HTTPS.